# How to disable unified address bar in safari 6

Tags: macos, safari

Did anyone find a way to get back the separate address and search bar? This unified thing is driving me mad.

I searched for this for quite some time now and found several people asking the same thing, unfortunately all of these ended in long discussions why this is a good thing and you don't want to change it.

I'm not interested in discussions. I want to turn that thing off. It doesn't work for me.

So far I found two things:

- [AnySearch](https://github.com/mcs07/AnySearch-safari-extension): This allows you to disable the search completely, but does not provide a separate search box
- [Glims](https://www.macupdate.com/app/iphone/27708/glims): Does a lot of things (for example turn off these stupid wide tabs), but not the unified bar problem.